# Python pickle module

Tags: python, module, pickle

I am noot use but i guess i heard that pickle module in preserves data structures in a file. So i wanted to try it out but i got an error in my code
Here is my code:

```
import pickle

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    pickle.dump(12.3, f)

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)

print(x)
```

I get an error whenever i run this code can someone say me why i am using python 3.9.5

Comment: you need to read and write binary. Try `"wb"` and `"rb"`. in your open`s

Comment: Ok so that will work right?

Comment: But a .txt file is not a binary file

Comment: pickle is not writing in text but in binary - regardless of the file name. You could use `dumps` to see it as a byte array and write that to a text file, but this does not add any value. Just try it

Comment: So if i write `f = open("test.txt", "rb") ` and then `o = f.read()` why i get an error

Comment: depends on wjat you are doing. But why are you doing `f.read()`, You already have `pickle.load()`  to read from the file.

Comment: OK so pickle.load() reads the file i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, you need to interface with your file in binary mode by using `'wb'` and `'rb'`. Additionally, as your file is binary and is not a text file, it's best not to use the `.txt` extention; it's convention to use the `.pickle` extention. An implementation of this is shown below:

```
import pickle
    
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(12.3, f)
    pickle.dump([1, 2, 3], f)

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)
    print(f'{x}, of type {type(x)}')
    y = pickle.load(f)
    print(f'{y}, of type {type(y)}')
```

Comment: Ok but i saw in a book of python with version 2.7 and it worked for them with using r and w modes

Comment: That might just be an odd python 2 feature, always best to stick with python 3

Comment: Yes actually when i bought a python book i was first introduced to programming and i was  i was 11 and i did not have a pc earlier so i just bought a book of python but i did not know the version was python 2.x so i often get confused with things as long integers whichb was there in python 2 but not python 3 but the explanation of things in the books is nice like funtions, exception which i will learn later

Comment: Highly recomend 'sentdex' on youtube, he does great python video's if you're keen to learn

Comment: Ok i will check his channel later

Answer (score 1):

```
`
import pickle
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop")
f = open("test.txt", "wb")
data = 12.3
pickle.dump(data, f)
pickle.dump([1, 2, 3], f)
f.close()
f = open("test.txt", "rb")
x = pickle.load(f)
print(x)
print(type(x))
y = pickle.load(f)
print(y)
print(type(y))
f.close()
`
```